# Filezilla set default permission 700 when new file upload on server

Tags: filezilla, ubuntu-16.04

Whenever I try to upload any file on server it takes default permission 700, But file is already exist on server and I replaced with another file from local then it never effect the old file permission on server. Please note I am using ubuntu 16.04 and filezilla version 3.25.2. Can any one help me to reset the default file permission in filezilla client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Default permission on server is set via the 'umask' command.   And individual accounts can override it under their login profile with the 'umask' command as well.   Filezilla client or any ftp client can't change the permission.

Comment: When i am uploading from another sytem with same FTP user, there is no problem with default permission.